# ugrade npm and express js to recent version

Tags: node.js, express

In my machine I installed recent node.js version but my npm version is 1.4.28 and express version is 2.5.8.

I tried using :npm update express -g

but it didn't work

How to upgrade this npm and express to recent version???

Answer (score 0):

To install latests npm run:
`curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`

To install latest `express` globally run:
`npm install -g express` (maybe with `sudo`)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I don't think you can `update` from 2.x to 3.x. You will have to do `npm uninstall express -g` and then `npm install express -g` to get the newer version. `update` seems to only work on minor/patch versions.

Also, npm comes with node now. How did you install node? I'd suggest you use `nvm` or `n`.